How to map non-existant user for ghe-migrator
I'm migrating repos from BitBucket Server to GitHub Enterprise Server using the ghe-migrator tool.
I have a user that was used by an old build tool, but isn't available as a user for the new GitHub server (because we're using AzureAD with github). When I try to use the rename action, the import fails because it can't create the user (again because it's setup to use AzureAD for users). There doesn't appear to be any good documentation for how to get past this online.
model_name,source_url,target_url,recommended_action,notes
user,https://bitbucket.internaldomain.com/users/gh_migrator,https://ghe.internaldomain.com/robo_server,map,
user,https://bitbucket.internaldomain.com/users/jbloggs,https://ghe.internaldomain.com/jbloggs,map,
user,https://bitbucket.internaldomain.com/users/robo_buildtool,,rename,Invalid value in url

Attempts to import this user:
user,https://bitbucket.internaldomain.com/users/robo_buildtool,https://ghe.internaldomain.com/robo_buildtool,map
user,https://bitbucket.internaldomain.com/users/robo_buildtool,https://ghe.internaldomain.com/robo_buildtool,rename,

